# ajax content is not loading in jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs

HI I had a weird situation with jquery tabs.I had two tabs that will load form using ajax options,everything look good but have small problem with document.ready function.

When after first loading i had two jquery chain selects in two forms that is one form in each tab . I had same jquery chain selects that will load with document.ready(function).

The thing is when i went to second tab the jquery select is not working because it is called by using document.ready function.

Is there any other way where i can call that jquery chain select instead of document.ready .
like once the tab loads or like that?

Thanks

Comment: paste some example code please.

Answer (score 0):

You need write the call to $(selector).tabs() again in the ajax success definition. If you re refreshing the contents on the tabs, the tabs will dissappear if you dont renderize again the tabs.